# Excel - General formula to reference a cell in a certain column with varying row

Tags: excel

In my worksheet in column F I have a list of names, that may appear or disappear according to other inputs in the spreadsheet. I want the cells in the `columns G:AZ` to remain blank if the corresponding cell (i.e. same row) in `column F` is also blank. Because I have thousands of cells to which I need to apply this, I'm using `Pullover's Macro Creator` to add this small change to all the formulas inside the cells really quickly, so I can do entire columns in seconds. In `column J`, for example, I've been applying this formula:

```vb
=IF(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0))=1,"",[this part changes and doesn't matter])
```

You can see that I need to change that `"-4"` to different numbers according to the column I'm working on. But I have so many columns that it's still going to be a pain to change that hundreds of times.

**My question:** Is there a formula I can use in the `COUNTBLANK` function that can reference the corresponding cell in `column F` without needing any changes in different columns and different rows? And since the `INDIRECT` formula is so volatile (I still don't know what that means, but I guess it's bad), is there a solution that doesn't use this formula?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(F:F,ROW())),"","blah")`. Btw, volatile means that Excel will re-calculate that specific formula over and over again on any change made anywhere in your workbook, even upon saving etc.

Comment: Indirect (and other volatile functions are bad if you use them in thousands and thousands of cells as they slow down recalculation. 

If you want to use your formula nevertheless do use absolte rather than relative references .. RC6 instead of RC[-4] would look in column F regardless of which column you are in    ([-4] means "go 4 columns left' while C6 means 'go to column 6'